# Rules governing "quite a [adjective]" word order

Tags: adverbs, word-order, colors

As part of an answer on another StackExchange site, I have a sentence reading, in part, "[A religious manual] which has quite a long section on [the subject of the question] says ..."

I was looking at this construction and thinking about whether I should say *quite a long section* or *a quite long section*—they seem to mean the same thing. Then I began wondering about the construction "quite a[n] [adjective]" in general. It looks as if I can say something is *quite a large X* or *a quite large X*; *quite a long X* or *a quite long X*; but, for example, neither **quite a purple X* nor **a quite purple X*.

I'm trying to solidify in my mind:

1. The rules governing when I can say *quite a[n] [adjective] [noun]* in the first place
2. The rules governing when I can invert this to *a quite [adjective ] [noun]*
3. Whether there are any other adverbs besides *quite* which can be inverted in this way.

Is there a name for this inversion? What sorts of elements does it apply to?

Comment: Google finds quite a few hits for "quite a red" and "quite a purple", so I wouldn't call it ungrammatical.

Comment: That's interesting. I had no hesitation in calling this ungrammatical initially, because it seems to be ungrammatical in my idiolect - it still seems a very strange usage to me, but I suppose others do use it.

Comment: To me, it doesn't seem like there's anything wrong with it.

Comment: Perhaps not to you; but it surprised me. What about the other elements of the question?

Comment: I can't think of a case where *quite a(n) [adjective]* can't be inverted to *a quite [adjective]*. But I could easily be missing some obvious ones.

Comment: And are there any other adjective-modifying adverbs that can be inverted in this way? (Note: I don't know that "quite _the_ [adjective]" has the same connotation as "quite _a[n]_ [adjective]"; and it appears to me that one can't invert it in the same way and retain the same meaning.

Comment: Quite an array of usages for _quite_, with and without articles, is laid out in the OED listing. It's quite too long to quote here.

Comment: Perhaps put a brief summary into an answer?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26628/quite-an-institution-meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word quite describes the degree of intensity to which the adjective modifies the noun. If I say that something is quite big, then it should be understood to mean that the thing is bigger than many things but not as big as it could be. It might be less common to discuss varying degrees of purple, but I don't think I would call it ungrammatical to do so. I would say that the answer to your first question is that you can say 'quite a(n) x' any time the adjective can have its intensity modified. I can't think of an example where I could say 'a very x' and not 'quite a(n) x' (assuming very to mean 'to a great degree' and not its alternate meaning).

Comment: Can "a quite" be inverted to "quite a" in all such cases?

Comment: This requires some serious and detailed analysis. One of the first things to consider is that the secondary/degree modifier 'quite' has contrasting meanings: It is quite easy = It is fairly easy // He was quite dead = He was stone dead.